# Apache utilizing more memory continuously

Tags: php, apache, web-hosting

I have a quite large website running in centos server. It carries out a lot of shell commands and runs a lot of MySQL queries. Everything seems fine. Running quite well. But at the same moment Apache is utilizing a lot of memory continuously. As far as I know the memory utilized by Apache should be freed once the script execution is completed but it's not like that in my case.

Is this some kind of problem in my code that makes Apache utilize more memory or should I be checking other stuff also?

Comment: What's the Apache and PHP versions?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately Apache processes won't return memory used by mod_php. You have to restart/recycle the Apache processes once in a while. Check out the configuration value [MaxRequestsPerChild](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mpm_common.html#maxrequestsperchild) which will do this for you automatically (it's off by default on CentOS if I recall correctly).

Set it to something low, but not too low since recycling is expensive. A few hundreds will probably do.